# MS Access find a substring with special pattern

Tags: regex, ms-access, text

In MS Access, I want to find the position of substring that starts with dot (.), space and uppercase letter. For example, if I have the string "Ok. I am ok with that.", it will give me "I am ok with that". Or to just give the position where this substring starts - in this case it will be 4. Any idea how this can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for the following regex:

`\.\s[A-Z].*`

Comment: I want this to give me a position or substring, not to find if it has that pattern (because all data have that pattern)

Comment: @user1680859, I have updated my answer. This will give you the rest of the string after the required regex match.

Comment: I am trying something like "InStr([text]," \.\s[A-Z].*")", but it gives me 0s

Comment: I figured out that I should add a reference to microsoft vbscript regular expressions. Then write a function that will implement the regex given. It worked!